# Translations of self-inserting keys

Tags: input-method, self-insert-command

What exactly determines what is inserted by
`self-insert-command`?  If I change the input-method to `greek`,
`p` will insert `π`, but will still be bound to
`self-insert-command`, though it patently does not insert itself.  `C-h k p` will say that `p` is still
bound to `self-insert-command` and that `p` was translated to
`π`, but says nothing more about this translation.
Any hints as to how I might have found the answer to this myself (using EMACS) would be appreciated too.

PS.  I realize the question may not be entirely clear.  To put it differently, what is the simplest way to let `a` insert `foo`, while remaining bound to `self-insert-command`?  Does this *have to* be done by an input method, or does *translation* indicate something more general?

Comment: +1 for "Any hints as to how I might have found the answer to this myself (using EMACS) would be appreciated too."

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>M-x describe-input-method greek RET</kbd> should tell you a lot already. Also the contents of lisp/leim/quail/greek.el are pretty self-explanatory (which is not the case for all input methods).

See [Input Methods](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Input-Methods.html) and [Reading Input](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Reading-Input.html) for more details (both of which are available in Emacs Info).

Comment: Assuming that I've got the sequence correct, emacs reads an event (e.g. a key press), passes it through keyboard translation, then passes it through the input method function, *then* gives the result  to `self-insert-command`. Even within `self-insert-command` there is one more level of translation through the `translation-table-for-input` before it is passed to `internal-self-insert` (which for now at least remains a black box to me).